# How to I get the advertising info sent by my beacons using the Altbeacon library?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I used the sample code from altbeacon. I can see a beacon and get the beacon's info (distance,etc).

How do I get the stuff broadcasted by the beacons? The nRf connect app and the Beacon manager apps can see the ibeacon, Eddystone and Physical web advertisements.

What do I need to do using the Altbeacon library to get the advertisements?
I can't find any examples at the AltBeacon site.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the stuff broadcasted by the beacons"?  The fact that you can see a beacon basically means you are reading this information - beacons typically send out just an identifier and signal calibration values needed to estimate distance.  In the case of Physical web, the identifier is in a format that may be decompressed into a URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked over my code after getting some rest and saw I was getting the info I wanted.